# Retrieve data from Firebase in Recycler view using fragment take too much time

Tags: firebase, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am using two fragments in the main activity, In first fragment[FirstFragment] load data from firebase and show in Recycler view, In the second fragment[uploadUserCarInformation] take data from user and store at the firebase,
I am facing **a problem when the application starts then first fragment load very quickly and data show but when replace the first fragment from the second fragment and when replacing back from the second fragment to the first fragment then take 4 to 5 minutes to load data from firebase in recyclerView.**
Kindly tell me where I modify the code,

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Fragment fragment1 = new FirstFragment();
    Fragment fragment2 =new SecondFragment();


    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
// get the reference of FrameLayout and TabLayout
        tabLayout=findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
        simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment1);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

// perform setOnTabSelectedListener event on TabLayout
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                // get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        tab.getIcon().setColorFilter(null);
                        fragmentReplace(fragment1,"fragment1");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        fragmentReplace(fragment2,"fragment2");
                        break;
                }

            }


            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }
    public void fragmentReplace(Fragment fragment,String fragmentName)
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
        Log.d("Running Fragment",fragmentName+ " is running");
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

**FirstFragment**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private ImageAdapter mAdapter;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;
    private List<carInformation> mUpload;

    View view;

    public FirstFragment() {
// Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //retrieveAndSendData();
        Log.d("Lifecycle","onCreate called");

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Lifecycle","onCreateView called");

        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first,container,false);
        mRecyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
     return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Lifecycle","onViewCreate called");
        retrieveAndSendData();


    }

    public void  retrieveAndSendData()
    {
        mUpload=new ArrayList<>();

        mDatabaseRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        ValueEventListener valueEventListener=new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            //get firebase data using datasnapshot (read data)
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                    DatabaseReference databaseReference=mDatabaseRef.child(key);

                    for (DataSnapshot child:  postSnapshot.getChildren())
                    {
                        String userBookId = child.getKey();
                        if(userBookId.equals("city") )
                        {
                            break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
//                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),userBookId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            databaseReference.child(userBookId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    carInformation userInformationObj=dataSnapshot.getValue(carInformation.class);
                                    mUpload.add(userInformationObj);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                }

                mAdapter = new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),mUpload);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),databaseError.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };

        mDatabaseRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

    }
```

**uploadUserCarInformation**

```
    public class uploadUserCarInformation extends Fragment {
    View view;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    StorageReference storageReference;
    private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    ImageView imageView;
    static int  PICK_IMAGE=1;
    Spinner spin;
//    mdatabase.push().getkey() -> generate uniqe id

    RadioGroup radioGroupCondition,radioGroupTransmission,radioGroupSupported;
    RadioButton radioButtonCondition,radioButtonTranmission,radioButtonSupported;
    String radioButtonConditionString,radioButtonSupportedString,radioButtonTransmissionString;
    Button addCar,signout;
    int selectedIdCondition,selectedIdTransmission,selectedIdSupported;
    String ownerName,carName,phoneNuberString,countryString;
    TextInputLayout name,carNamePlusModel,phoneNumber,country;

    carInformation car_Information=new carInformation();

    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Uri imageUri;

    String[] bankNames=new String[374];
    InputStream in;
    int i=0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_user_car_information,container,false);

        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        storageReference=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        name=view.findViewById(R.id.textFieldCarOwner);
        carNamePlusModel=view.findViewById(R.id.textFieldCarNameModel);
        phoneNumber=view.findViewById(R.id.textFieldPhoneNumber2);
        addCar=view.findViewById(R.id.addCar);
        signout=view.findViewById(R.id.sign_out);
        progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
//        progressBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(
//                Color.RED, android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

        radioGroupCondition=view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupCarCondtion);
        radioGroupSupported=view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupCarSupport);
        radioGroupTransmission=view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroupCarTransmission);

//        progressBar=new ProgressBar(getActivity());

        spin = view.findViewById(R.id.Countryspinner2);

        imageView=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.selectImage);
        //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.select_image);

        try
        {
            InputStream fr = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.cities);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fr));
            ArrayList<String> lines=new ArrayList<String>();
            String currentLine=br.readLine();

            while(currentLine!=null)
            {
                lines.add(currentLine);
                currentLine=br.readLine();

            }
            Collections.sort(lines);
            fr.close();    //closes the stream and release the resources

            for(String line : lines)
            {
                bankNames[i]=line;
//                System.out.println(line);
                i++;
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,bankNames);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }



        };

        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
        spin.setAdapter(aa);


        signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
        Fragment  fragment = new SecondFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
            }
        });
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onFileChooser();
            }
        });

        addCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mUploadTask !=null && mUploadTask.isInProgress())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Uploading Task",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    carImageAndDetailUploading();
                }

           }


        });



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
                imageUri = data.getData();

                //A powerful image downloading and caching library and get image from library  for Android
                Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imageUri).into(imageView);

        }
    }

    private void carImageAndDetailUploading()
    {
        FirebaseUser user=firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(user.getUid());



        selectedIdCondition=radioGroupCondition.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButtonCondition=view.findViewById(selectedIdCondition);
        radioButtonConditionString=radioButtonCondition.getText().toString();

        selectedIdSupported=radioGroupSupported.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButtonSupported=view.findViewById(selectedIdSupported);
        radioButtonSupportedString=radioButtonSupported.getText().toString();

        selectedIdTransmission=radioGroupTransmission.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        radioButtonTranmission=view.findViewById(selectedIdTransmission);
        radioButtonTransmissionString=radioButtonTranmission.getText().toString();

        ownerName=name.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        carName=carNamePlusModel.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        phoneNuberString=phoneNumber.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
        countryString=spin.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(ownerName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(carName) || TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNuberString) || TextUtils.isEmpty(countryString))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Please fill the empty fields ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return; //return stooping the function to execute further
        }
        else if(imageUri == null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No file Selected ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        long phone=Long.parseLong(phoneNuberString);


        car_Information.setCarName(carName);
        car_Information.setOwnerName(ownerName);
        car_Information.setUserPhoneNumber(phone);
        car_Information.setCountry(countryString);
        car_Information.setCarCondtion(radioButtonConditionString);
        car_Information.setCarSupported(radioButtonSupportedString);
        car_Information.setCarTransmission(radioButtonTransmissionString);


        StorageReference fileReference=storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+ "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));
        mUploadTask =  fileReference.putFile(imageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        //below code user can see 100 % progress bar for 5 sec
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        },5000);

                        String uniqueKey=databaseReference.push().getKey();
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while (!urlTask.isSuccessful());
                        Uri downloadUrl = urlTask.getResult();
                        car_Information.setImageUrl(downloadUrl.toString());
                        car_Information.setUnique_key(uniqueKey);
//                        databaseReference.child("car details"+car_Information.getUnique_key());
//                        databaseReference.child("car details"+car_Information.getUnique_key()).setValue(car_Information);
                        databaseReference.child(car_Information.getUnique_key());
                        databaseReference.child(car_Information.getUnique_key()).setValue(car_Information);

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Successfully Upload",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();




                        clear_editText();



                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress=(100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                        progressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                    }
                });
    }


    private  void onFileChooser()
    {
        Intent intent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent,PICK_IMAGE);
        //startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"),PICK_IMAGE);
    }
    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri)
    {
        //this method for get file extension
        ContentResolver cR=getActivity().getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime=MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void clear_editText()
    {
        name.getEditText().setText(" ");
        carNamePlusModel.getEditText().setText(" ");
        phoneNumber.getEditText().setText(" ");
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg4xn.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsZJj.jpg)